# How to filter any array elements if they contains other array elements?

Tags: json, filter, jq

Consider the following json:

```
[
  {
    "val": 1,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "val": 2,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "val": 3,
    "name": "c"
  }
]
```

I want to pass an argument of space separated elements to jq and filter only these elements that have names matching to one of the argument elements. The following does not work, and I do not understand why - it only filters the first element. I suspect that `$input` is not updated. I do not know how to "join streams" to make it possible to use both streams at the same time - I have one stream the input and another is `$names | split(" ")`.

```
$ jq -r --arg names 'a c' '.[] | select(. as $input | $names | split(" ") | index($input.name) == 0)' 1.json 
{
  "val": 1,
  "name": "a"
}
```

I have jq-1.5 available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the comparison using `IN` (or `any` for jq < 1.6), for example:

```bash
# jq 1.6
jq --arg names 'a c' '.[] | select(IN(.name; ($names / " ")[]))'

# jq 1.5
jq --arg names 'a c' '.[] | select(any(.name == ($names / " ")[]; .))'
```

If your search keys are unique, you could also build up an `INDEX`, and lookup the fields:

```bash
# jq 1.6
jq --arg names 'a c' 'INDEX(.name)[($names / " ")[]]'

# jq 1.5
jq --arg names 'a c' 'map({key:.name, value:.}) | from_entries[($names / " ")[]]'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "name": "a"
}
{
  "c": 3,
  "name": "c"
}
```

Comment: I am getting `jq: error: IN/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:`. `jq-1.5`

Comment: Then you have an older version of `jq`. You can use `any` instead: `jq -r --arg names 'a c' '.[] | select(any(keys[] == ($names / " ")[]; .))'`

Comment: the key is misleading here. Sorry, my bad, I should have made the json with more unique properties.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the updated input JSON.

Comment: Yup, the second one works. I learned today the `any([array here];.)` trick and `element == [array][]` trick. Thanks

Comment: You can find more "tricks" looking at [how some of the internal commands are defined](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L292-L293), e.g. `IN` (jq 1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probably to split your `names` into an array first, then use [`IN`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#SQL-StyleOperators) to filter your stream:

```
jq -r --arg names 'a c' '($names/" ") as $names
| .[] | select(.name | IN($names[]))'
```

Or using [`any`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#any,any(condition),any(generator;condition)):

```
jq -r --arg names 'a c' '($names/" ") as $names
| .[] | select(any(.name == $names[]; .))'
```

(the latter simply inlines `IN`: `def IN(s): any(s == .; .);`)