# Unable to resolve an array in bash using jq

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to put an array in the `inside()` function. If I hard code like this `inside(["test, coverage"])` then my code works fine. However if I try to put it dynamically using variable called jobs_to_copy then it throws error. If you see the echo statement (`echo $jobs_to_copy`), it does print in this required format ["test","coverage"] but not sure why this error is still coming then.

This is my Bash shell script:-

```
#!/bin/sh

CI_JOBS="test, coverage"

jobs_to_copy=$(echo $CI_JOBS | sed 's/, /,/g' | jq -Rc 'split(",")')
echo $jobs_to_copy

JOBS=$(cat jobs.json | jq '.[] | select(([.name] | inside($jobs_to_copy)) and .artifacts_file != null) | .id')
echo $JOBS
```

**Error:-**

```
["test","coverage"]
jq: error: jobs_to_copy/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select(([.name] | inside($jobs_to_copy)) and .artifacts_file != null) | .id                               
jq: 1 compile error
```

I had debugged a lot but I'm really stuck on this and never thought it is going to be so tricky.
Kindly let me know its fix

Comment: What's the content of jobs.json?

Comment: `$jobs_to_copy` isn't interpreted as a shell variable, because it's inside simple quotes.

Comment: okay, how to fix it? @Amessihel

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75660442/how-to-filter-any-array-elements-if-they-contains-other-array-elements answer your question?

Comment: The given link is about select/index....I'm using inside function

Comment: sorry, I really did not understand when hardcoding one is working then why not $jobs_to_copy is not get interpreted. Is it something to do quotes?

Comment: @vinod827 https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/, especially "Variables" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `$jobs_to_copy` to be substituted with the variable value, don't use single quotes but rather double quotes.

In your case, that'd look like this:

```bash
JOBS=$(cat jobs.json | jq '.[] | select(([.name] | inside('"$jobs_to_copy"')) and .artifacts_file != null) | .id')
```

This first closes the literal, then substitutes in the variable value (in double quotes to prevent having it break out of that area), and finally, starts the literal again

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the only issue. `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')'', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`. This question seems too broad.

Comment: oh true, they seem to have added an additional bracket... I suppose the second bracket of  `$jobs_to_copy"'))` is wrong